# Python2.7 ~ tilde not recognized in path as home directory macOs

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal, environment-variables

At some point the tilde symbol ~ was no longer recognized as my home directory, only in Python. ~ still works with in terminal, so I'm not sure what happened but any insight on how to fix it you will save me some typing thanks!

On macOs Mojave

```
import os
tilde = '~'
print(os.path.exists(tilde))
os.system("if test -d ~; then echo 'exists'; fi")
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
exists
```

Comment: The tilde is a shortcut recognized by your shell, not an alternate name for your home directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) on the path first. Try

```
print(os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser(tilde)))
```

instead.

Answer (score 5):

The `~` is interpreted by the OS, not Python. The way to use it from Python script is:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
```

now `home` will have the path denoted by `~`